# Multiply form window in grid

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I have some window in WPF, in window I have multiple controls.

In this window I draw some chart and display some information for one line (production line, I have Line column in database). Now I want to display for example chart for 4, 6, 9 production lines. Can I automatize this operation? Some grid where I can set `X=3`, `Y=3` and in each cell I will display chart and information for different lines. Right now I am creating multiple window objects and align it to imitate grid.

Can someone give me advice?

Answer (score 0):

I created UserControl from my window and now I just add this control to UniformGrid.